# ZEND: Return HTML as string using Render?

Tags: zend-framework

I have:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
$this->render("voucher-list");
```

The problem is, when I execute:

```
$this->render("voucher-list");
```

It actually prints the information to screen. I want to return the data as an HTML string. This DOES NOT work:

```
$htmlcontent = $this->render("voucher-list");
```

How would I go about returning this information as a string?

Comment: are you print the data of voucher-list on other page.

Comment: i want to ultimately put it in a json object to return it using an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the data into JSON format then you need to make the array of data and use  the following code to send the data:

```
  $data = array(3,4,'test', 'my-name' => 3,4); //suppose this is your data
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
  $this->view->layout()->disableLayout(); 
  echo Zend_Json::encode($data);
```

And you will get the data in JSON format.

See this: [Zend Framework JSON Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715700/zend-framework-json-output)